# NextJS's SCSS is completely chaotic in the production environment & Antd is also ineffective

Tags: javascript

I have a Nextjs project running in a local environment and everything is working fine. I want to use Docker to deploy and go live on cloud servers. But in the production environment, all styles are messy.

I'm wondering if there might be a configuration issue?

1. my DockerFile

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
#RUN \
#  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
#  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
#  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
#  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
#  fi

RUN yarn config set registry 'https://registry.npmmirror.com/'
RUN yarn install

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN yarn build

# If using npm comment out above and use below instead
# RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

#ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

#RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
#RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

#COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Set the correct permission for prerender cache
#RUN mkdir .next
#RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
#COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
#COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder /app/.next/static ./.next/static
COPY --from=builder /app/.next/server ./.next/server

#USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3002

ENV PORT 3002
# set hostname to localhost
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

2. next.config.js

```
const nextConfig = {
    target: 'server',
    webpack(config) {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.svg$/,
            use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
        });

        return config;
    },
    output: "standalone",
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Perhaps it's another reason, but I don't have any ideas now. I hope some friends can provide useful solutions or ideas. If you need any other information, you can leave a message and I will provide it for you. Thank you for your help.